# .NET Forms MySQLConnection 404 Error

Tags: mysql, asp.net, http-status-code-404, database-connection

I am building a .net webform application with form authentication, it works fine on my local machine but when I deploy it and copy it over to my server for some reason it gives me a 404 error on the login page which is really weird because the page does exist.

In my web.config I have the following set;

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms cookieless="UseCookies" loginUrl="~/login.aspx" defaultUrl="/" name="mydomain.co.uk" path="/" protection="All" requireSSL="true" timeout="30" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users ="?" />
      <allow users = "*" />
    </authorization>
```

When I try to access my website it sends me correctly to the login page as expected but I then get the 404 error saying;

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /login.aspx
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34237

In my application pool I have set the website to use .NET Framework V4.0 but now I'm just a bit stuck on how to fix the issue.

My server is Windows Web Server 2008 R2

Cheers

----------*** UPDATE ***----------

OK, so I think I have nailed the problem down to my MySQL connection, all seems fine until I set up a new connection like so

```
Public cCon As New MySqlConnection
```

I have installed the MySQL connector for .NET and I import the connector like so

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
```

but if I try and create a New MySqlConnection then the page will give me a 404 error. Using this on my local machine is not a problem, and the MySQL database is sitting on the remote server, even when I access it from my local machine I am accessing the MySQL database on the server.

Cheers

Comment: do you have the permission to read/modify the file on the server?

Comment: Are you using any third party .dll or some thing that you have install on your local system but not on the server?

Comment: I am using a MySQL connector which I have installed on both my local and remote machines, however if this was the problem would it not give me an alternative error message?

Comment: Yes I have permission to read/modify the files on both machines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got it working, I'm sure all of you guys are rolling your eyes at me now, but on deploying my website I presumed that the MySQL.Data.dll would also be packaged with it, but it wasn't, so to fix my problem all I did was to copy MySQL.Data.dll to my bin folder of my website and voila!

Sorry if I've wasted everybody's time.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure you have the necessary permissions on the server, the file you try to reach exists and is located at the place you expect it to be, you are using the right domain, also, make sure the service you intend to reach is running and there is no route redirecting you on the server.

Comment: I have all of the correct read/modify permissions set up on the site, the file definitely exists where it is supposed to, the domain is correct as I can navigate to another page on the domain that is part of my project that is not authenticated so it doesn't need to forward me to the login page. The only service I need to access is MySQL and that is running as I have classic ASP websites using the MySQL database.

Comment: Are you sure you are not using an incorrect relative path?

Comment: Absolutely positive, please see my update to my main post which gives more insight into the problem to do with MySqlConnection, cheers.